# Python web scraping data-val?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i want to get the 'last' value from this site (https://www.kraken.com/charts) and use it for my own project i already have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.kraken.com/charts")
page

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

euro = soup.find(class_="val mono").get_text()

euro = float(euro)
```

but this wil return a string instead of a data-val. does anyone know how i can select the data-val instead of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select it this way:

```
euro = soup.find(class_="val mono")
euro_val = euro['data-val']
```

Comment: can i ask you another fast question?

Comment: I want to grab the 'last' number from this website now: https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-STRAT but it is inside a span that is inside a div, how can i do that?

Comment: Basically you can select the element this way: `last = soup.find(attrs={'data-bind':'text: summary.displayLast()'})` but it will return you the element without the text because the text is loaded dynamically and bf don't have access to it. For dynamic pages you can try the `Selenium` way and add a sleep after opening the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147730/discussion-between-alex-lucaci-and-fluffyme).